# I am trying to web scrape text from a website and randomly generate words in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, web

This is my code below. Nothing is appearing except for my hardcoded words in the array.

```
class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {

   var strawberry = ["Cocktails" , " Theres a maniac in the mailbox" , " Kims goat feet" , " Pineapple juice" , "Hamster", "Ski" , "Monica is fat" ]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func funnyButtonPressed() {


    let url = URL(string: "http://thoughtcatalog.com/jim-goad/2014/12/400-euphemisms-for-sexual-intercourse/")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }

        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        self.strawberry.append(string!) 
        print("\(string)")
    }

    task.resume()

    self.activeConversation?.insertText(strawberry[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(strawberry.count)))])

}
```

Comment: You need to insert the word *inside* the closure; you are setting the text. Fore the fetch has completed asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Im not understanding could you show me? @Paulw11

Comment: The code in braces after `let task =` is a closure that will be executed when the data has been fetched from the network. This is after some time as network operations take time. The `self.activeConversation?.insert...` will execute immediately after the task is started by `resume` before the data has been fetched. You need to move that inside the closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 I moved self.activeConversation inside but every time i click the button nil appears in the console